# Mac os not showing after install windows 10 with boot camp

Tags: bootcamp

[image: image3]

I'm unable to switch windows to Mac os after installation of Windows 10. working only with restart and holding options key. why this boot camp not working.

Attached screenshots for reference:
[image: image1]

[image: image1]

Answer (score 2):

The Boot Camp software for certain model Macs can be upgraded after being installed. This upgrade will allow Windows to choose a macOS operating systems stored in a APFS container as the default to boot. The upgrade can be performed by running Apple Software Update while booted to Windows.